# Is experienced gained during a mission retained after death?

Tags: infamous

I've been playing inFamous since PSN gave it away for free.  I've been getting the hang of the game but, I've died quite a few times, generally by charging headlong into overwhelming force.  I can usually get a few kills before I'm overwhelmed, I die, and then I rush right back into it.  I'm wondering what happens to that XP that I gained from the kills before I died.  **Does it apply instantly, or only at the end of a misson
?**.

Alternatively, the question could also be phrased "**Is it to my long-term benefit to die many times per mission so that I can grind XP for killing the same creeps over and over when I restart?**"

Comment: Your question title is a bit misleading as you aren't asking so much about grinding as you are about whether or not XP gained during a mission is retained after dying. It's been a while since I played, but as far as I remember you can just run around without an active mission and still gain XP, so I would imagine XP is not mission bound (though I have no idea how it is effected by death). I recall you spend XP to purchase upgrade, so perhaps you could keep track of the available purchase points to test this out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finished it last weekend after snagging my free copy, as well. Your XP will stick with you, though I found that most of the baddies don't get replaced. There is a limit to how many bad guys are in each area. Some moments have respawning bad guys as they are needed for plot points, but overall, after an enemy is killed, he does not come back.

That said, I thought the pacing of the game was great and didn't see any need for leveling. I did all of the side missions when they were presented and progressed through the leveling system just fine.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a little while, but as I recall, death doesn't affect your XP at all, regardless of when or how you gain it.